# Excel: Median of even number of values with a condition

Tags: excel, median

When I calculate the median of even numbers for e.g 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.. i want the return value to be 5 i.e. the higher value of the two middle values and not the average of 4 & 5. Please help

Comment: If the numbers are sorted then the value that you want (which is an order statistic rather than a median) can be calculated by taking the median of the numbers obtained by throwing away the first value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. but sorry I forgot to mention that the values may not be in any specific order

Answer (score 4):

I don't have Excel, so I can't try it, but I think you should be able to accomplish this with a combination of the `LARGE` function the `COUNT` function, and the `TRUNC` function.  For example, if the numbers you are working with are in cells `A1` through `A8`, you should be able to find the answer you want, though technically it's not the median, with the formula

```
=LARGE(A1:A8,TRUNC(COUNT(A1:A8)/2))
```

**Edit**

```
=LARGE(A1:A8,TRUNC((1+COUNT(A1:A8))/2))
```

If you know you will always be working with an even number of entries, the call to `TRUNC` could be omitted.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Tried your way but if there are odd number of elements the median is not what I get

Comment: @UpendraSarvaiya You *specifically* asked for how to compute this pseudo-median for an even number of elements. It thus isn't a very cogent response that a given solution doesn't work for an odd number of elements. In any event, it is easy-enough to wrap this solution in an `IF` function.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Hi, Sorry for not being very clear on what exactly I wanted. Please find below the link of the data file I am intending to apply the formula to
https://docs.google.com/a/scmhrd.edu/spreadsheets/d/1FyUmJNenhGa8mV52NgN9ux2yYtMHkTIkOkzQqhT6bmM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula was intended to handle both the even and odd case.  I think I was off by one in my handling of the odd case, though, and my edit should correct that problem.

Comment: @EvanVanderZee: I tried your updated formula, but it fetched me the lower of the 2 middle values. So I used an If statement as suggested by Gary's student. i.e. if odd then directly find the median orelse use the large function as suggested by you.. :P Thanks anyway.. :)

Comment: @UpendraSarvaiya: I had access to Excel for a while today.  I tried the edited formula, and it worked for me for both the even and odd case.  Conditionally using the median might be slightly faster for a long list of numbers, but I think the edited formula is correct.  Be careful about where you put the parentheses.

Comment: Worked perfectly :D.. I was misplacing the brackets.. Thanks alot.. :D

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**:

```
=IF(ISODD(COUNT(A:A)),MEDIAN(A:A),ROUNDUP(MEDIAN(A:A),0))
```

**EDIT#1:**

Consider the *array formula*:

```
=IF(ISODD(COUNT(A:A)),MEDIAN(A:A),MIN(IF(A:A>MEDIAN(A:A),A:A)))
```

If the number of values is odd, return the median. 
 If the number of value is even, return the smallest value greater than the median.

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

*This approach does not require the data to be sorted.*

**EDIT#2:**

This array formula appears to handle Ron's case:

```
=IF(ISODD(COUNT(A:A)),MEDIAN(A:A),MIN(IF(A:A>=MEDIAN(A:A),A:A)))
```

It returns the smallest value greater than or equal to the median *(for the even case)*

But I don't know if this is what the Poster wants.

Comment: Wouldn't this give the wrong answer if the numbers are not sequential?

Comment: @EvanVanderZee  You are correct!  I will withdraw this answer.

Comment: @EvanVanderZee  I *(hope)*, that I fixed the answer.

Comment: Consider:  `{1.2;1.2;1.3;1.3;1.3;1.3}`  Your formula seems to return a zero on my worksheet (Excel 2016)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  **OUCH**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: As it turns out, the OP did not provide the complete problem, and is having problem adapting the solutions to his real problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Figured it out.. Thanks alot.. :)

Comment: @UpendraSarvaiya  This turned out to be an interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LARGE(A1:A9,INT((COUNT(A1:A9)/2)+0.5))
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Round`after the `Median`
in your case you can type: `=ROUND(MEDIAN(B4:I4),0)`
lets say that the given range is from B4 to I4 from 1 to 8.

Comment: Note that the rounding up the average of two values is different from taking their maximum (unless those values are integers which differ by 1). I think that you misread the question.